# Setting Position of the textlabel inside the tableviewcell?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

In my application i am trying to adjust the position of the textlabel and detailtextlabel in a tableview cell.I am doing like this `

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
     static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        UIImageView* img = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cell_with_arrow.png"]];
        [cell setBackgroundView:img];
        [img release];  


    }

    cell.textLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0,0, 150, 40);
    cell.detailTextLabel.frame = CGRectMake(155, 55, 150, 40);
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:14.0];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.textLabel.text =@"name";
    cell.detailTextLabel.text=@" status";

     cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; 
    //cell.detailTextLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmenteft;
    //cell.textLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;

  return cell;
}
```

`but seems to be having no effect.can anybody help me to point me where i am going wrong?

Comment: Did you try to add a custom UILabel to tableviewcell's contentView?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`textLabel` and `detailTextLabel` are `readonly` so you can not change them.

```
@property(nonatomic, readonly, retain) UILabel *textLabel
@property(nonatomic, readonly, retain) UILabel *detailTextLabel
```

See [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewCell/textLabel)

Answer (score 2):

What I would suggest is that you could create your custom `UITableViewCell` instead, you will have more control over it's content and can add custom subviews in there as well.

Here are some tutorials for that:

[From IB](http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/custom-uitableviewcell/)

[From Code](http://jainmarket.blogspot.co.uk/2009/05/creating-custom-table-view-cell.html)

Answer (score 2):

you need to override layoutSubviews method

Create a customcell class and inherit with uitableviewcell

@try this code

**CustomCell.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell

@end
```

**CustomCell.m**

```
#import "CustomCell.h"

@implementation CustomCell

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString  *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)layoutSubviews{

    //Set here your frame

    self.textLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, , 320, 30);
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

@end
```